# How do I access the reporting services 2005 web service if it has an instance name

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to access a reporting services 2005 web service but I am unable to figure out how to do it. I have reporting services 2005 running on a server and it uses the instance name SQL2005.
The URL to access the reports manager is `http://myserver/Reports$SQL2005/Pages/Folder.aspx`. I tried going to `http://myserver/Reports$SQL2005/ReportService2005.asmx` and it didn't work. I tried various other combinations that didn't work.

I am able to access a reporting services web service for a 2008 web service on another server using the URL `http://otherserver/ReportServer/ReportService2008.asmx`. I am saying this to show that I am not completely stupid and unable to find a web service.

I believe that the instance name is somehow responsible for not being able to get the right URL for the web service.

Can anyone please tell me what URL I should be using to access the reporting services 2005 web service?

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty old question, but to help others I believe the correct URL for the web service on a SQL 2005 **named instance** is:

`http://yourserver/ReportServer$instancename/ReportService2005.asmx`

To browse the report manager, like you say it is:

`http://yourserver/Reports$instancename`

One thing I'm not sure about in your question is your link for a 2008 web service.  I believe under SQL 2008 it still uses a web service called `ReportService2005.asmx`.

Answer (score 0):

It should be along the lines of this

http://servername/reportserver/ReportService2005.asmx

I know that this has worked for me in the past so double check the instance name and server path

Comment: I tried that URL replacing servername with the name of my server but all I get is a page that says "Server Application Unavailable".

Answer (score 0):

To get to the server:

```
https://myserver/ReportServer/ReportService2005.asmx
```

which the report would be something like:

```
https://myserver/ReportServer/ReportService2005.asmx/folder/myreport
```

Also note that you'll want to make this a Web Rerference and not a Service Reference.

---

to ge all of the subscriptions for a report:

VB:

```
Dim rs As New reports.ReportingService2005()
rs.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(_userName, _passWord)
Dim subscriptions() As reports.Subscription = rs.ListSubscriptions(_reportName, "<DOMAIN>\" & _userName)
```

C#:

```
NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential(_userName, _passWord);
reports.ReportingService2005 rs = new reports.ReportingService2005();
rs.Credentials = credentials;

List<reports.Subscription> subscriptions = new List<reports.Subscription>();
foreach (reports.Subscription x in rs.ListSubscriptions("<report name>", "<domain>\<username>"))
     subscriptions.Add(x);
```

Answer (score -1):

http://[server name]/[report instance name]/ReportService2005.asmx?wsdl

this must work, that give lot of report server method

Comment: This is incorrect - the instance name must use the dollar notation as in my answer.